# Php-worker keeps growing in memory when running supervisor queue's

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd, laradock

When running supervisor queue's the memory of the php-worker container keeps rising. (As seen in docker stats)
[image: Imgur]

This number does not go down when the jobs are done.
When the queue keeps processing jobs for a while the memory reaches 100% and crashes.

```
[program:updater]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/laravel/artisan queue:work --daemon --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=1800 --queue=updater
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
numprocs=20
user=laradock
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel/storage/logs/updater.log
```

Is there something I'm missing about clearing the memory after jobs?

**EDIT 1:**
Logs:

```
[2019-08-07 16:26:36][4320] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:36][4385] Processing:
App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:36][4385] Processed:  App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:36][4386] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:37][4281] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:38][4314] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:38][4388] Processing: App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:38][4388] Processed:  App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:38][4389] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:40][4391] Processing: App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:40][4391] Processed:  App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:41][4368] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:41][4392] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:45][4371] Processed:  App\Jobs\UpdateClient
[2019-08-07 16:26:45][4394] Processing: App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:45][4394] Processed:  App\Listeners\Statuses\NewClientCreatedStatuses
[2019-08-07 16:26:45][4395] Processing: App\Jobs\UpdateClient
```

Comment: Does your logfile contains any error you could post?

Comment: @mdexp No, unfortunately it just shows the jobs being processed normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `--daemon` flag is the cause of your issues. This will make the process run in the background. My guess is that supervisor isn't able to kill the process anymore resulting in more and more processes being run. 
The [default laravel configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration) doesn't use this flag either.

Comment: Thanks, after checking the documentation there is nothing about --daemon after laravel 5.0. So I think this resolves the issue